# Fluentd copy output plugin not sending same data to both destinations?

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fluentd

I have a web server stack with multiple nodes (auto scaling group), and each web server is configured to use Fluentd to forward log files to a central collector which saves the logs in an S3 bucket.

I am testing a new collector, and configured the web servers to send a copy of an access log to both the old and the new collector, but there is a huge discrepancy in the aggregated files.

The old collector is saving 2x the log data. I can't figure out for the life of me what the issue is, unless the data is getting lost somewhere on the way to the new collector (and how could I best test this?).

**Web server td-agent.conf**

```
<source>
  type tail
  path /var/log/some/access.log
  tag some-access.log
  format tsv
  keys time,userId,position,userAgent,platform
  pos_file /tmp/fluent.some-access.log.pos
  rotate_wait
</source>

<match some-access.log>
  type copy
  <store>
    type forward
    <server>
      host log-collector-1.lan
      port 24224
    </server>
  </store>
  <store>
    type forward
    <server>
      host log-collector-2.lan
      port 24224
    </server>
  </store>
</match>
```

The log collectors have the exact same config... so no need to look there.

Answer (score 2):

I first heard such behaviour.
I assume log-collector-1.lan refers same server as log-collector-2.lan.

You didn't paste aggregator side configuration so just a guess.
How to check the 'saving 2x the log data'?

You can check fluentd receives logs or not by following way.

- Using monitor_agent to check S3's buffer size: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/monitoring#monitoring-agent
- fluent-tail command to check passed events: https://github.com/choplin/fluent-tail
- Using stdout and copy plugins to dump actual record.

Comment: I am sending to different servers. I've been trying different things all day, with no luck.
I have reverted back to the setup in my original post, and my results are better now, which leads me to believe it is a network issue or something similar.
I am on AWS by the way.